# Installing private node package from Bitbucket changing its codeline in package.json

Tags: bitbucket, pnpm

I have a private node package on bitbucket which is loading with an app-password in package.json, so it will also work with deployment pipelines:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-package": "git+https://<bitbucket-user>:<bitbucket-app-password>@bitbucket.org/my-workspace/my-package.git"
  }
}
```

It runs as expected and loads the package but everytime I run an update/install locally it changes the line into

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-package": "bitbucket:my-workspace/my-package",
  }
}
```

I assume this happens because of me having a git ssh connection to bitbucket. The second one still works locally but breaks when I am deploying.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?